# WordPress WooCommerce: give another button 'add to cart' function

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'd like to give another html element the function of 'add to cart'. Is this possible? I have added some html code into single-product.php and want one of these elements to function as 'add to cart' when you click on them :)

I hope that I've been able to explain myself :P

Comment: what is your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will work as an add to cart button within a product loop, where `$product` is the post object -

```
<?php if( $product->is_purchasable() ):?>
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
    <button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

</form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time! When I add that code to /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/demo/woocommerce/single-product.php it becomes a blank page :(

Comment: I just tested that exact code in single-product.php and it worked. Make sure your syntax is correct, and use WP DEBUG to check for any errors.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works like a charm! Although the button shows up at the bottom of the page, is it possible to make my html elements use this? Where it doesn't necessarily have to be a button? With a <div> or <a> or something?

BTW, I'm sorry for my late reply, was studying for school :) I really appreciate the help!!!